# How to create reusable component with simpleSchema

Tags: meteor, meteor-collection2, simple-schema

I might be thinking about this the wrong way, so please feel free to correct my thinking.

I'm using simpleSchema and I have a section of code which is used in more than one schema. Is there a way to create an individual component and import it into each schema, so that when I need to update the component I don't have to update it in multiple locations?

Path: `resuableComponent`

```
type: String,
  optional: true,
  autoform: {
    type: "select",
    options: function () {
      return [
        {label: "School logo 1", value: 'url'},
        {label: "School logo 2", value: 'url'},
        {label: "School logo 3", value: 'url'},
      ];
    },
  }
```

Path: `studentCollection.js`

```
Schemas.Student = new SimpleSchema({
    studentUserId: {
        type: String,
    },
    school: {
        type: String,
        optional: false
    },
    **resuableComponent**
});
```

Path: `teacherCollection.js`

```
Schemas.Teacher = new SimpleSchema({
    teacherUserId: {
        type: String,
    },
    school: {
        type: String,
        optional: false
    },
    **resuableComponent**
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move the reusable objects into a different file that should be visible on both client and server if you are using SimpleSchema.

Example based on your question:

`lib/schema-components.js` :

```
SchemaComponents = {
  school: {
    type: String,
    optional: false
  },
  // ...
  // more reusable components here
};
```

`someCollectionFile.js` :

```
Schemas.Student = new SimpleSchema({
    studentUserId: {
        type: String
    },
    school: SchemaComponents.school,
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that is almost working correctly. In my example I used `select`. For some reason when I implement your solution select menu doesn't appear. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I made a silly mistake. Scrap my last message. Your solution works perfectly! Thanks

Comment: I've just tried to use the same component in a separate schema and I keep getting the error, `ReferenceError: SchemaComponents is not defined` am I missing something?

Comment: Is your js file located into the /lib folder? I suggest you reading about [Meteor file load order](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#load-order)

Comment: I just read meteor load order and I've moved the collections folder into lib. I still get the same error when I use the schemaCompoents in more the one place. Any thoughts, have I missed something?